# Online Flash Video Combiner

Tags: flash

I want to develop a online karaoke site where users can select a video and start recording their voice.
Short flow chart will be like this.

Select Karaoke Video(**source video**) -> 
New Page with **Source Video and User's Webcam and Audio** -> 
Click recording will start Source video and start recording user's audio while playing source video.

When **Source Video end**, user's voice and source video are **combined** on the server and generate a recorded karaoke song.

By the way, karaoke songs are preloaded with only background and harmony.

So everything are server side.
Anyone can advice commercial or free software for my project? Thanks

Comment: How is Flash being used here? Is it for playing back the video? Do you require flv video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specification of your server OS would have been nice.
I can recommend **AviSynth**. It is a command line/script driven non-linear video editing application. Quite a learning curve, but if you master it, it can do anything (concerning audio&video ;-) ) for you.
Unfortunately, they have big problems with their site at the moment. You can find Information about it on
http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page
and there are some articles on doom9.org.

There is also good old **ffmepg**, which is available for some OSes and can do some things via commandline (not as powerful as AvySynth, but enough for simple muxing.

Also **VirtualDub** can be scripted. I did never use it without the GUI, but should do the same thing.

Last but not least **gstreamer**, very powerful, hard to hack.

Me guess would be, you think its only simple muxing and will find out soon, that you need much more for your purpose :-). Synchronicity of A\V can quickly become a problem here.

For linux systems also take a look at mencoder (closely tied to mplayer). There is a command line version available. As one smart guy said: THE swiss army knife for A\V-stuff.

Comment: Your informations are very useful. I'll try and check them out! By the way, have you ever seen this script(http://bit.ly/cgvEzR) and know the name? Thanks for your reply anyway!

Comment: It doesn't look familiar. Where did you find it? Maybe with some meta-information we can track it down.
Btw: could you accept my answer? I need 200 points to comment on questions and thats a thing I really need :-)